# FlatList not rendering data from json array React-native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList in React Native -

Here's my object that I'm passing on to FlatList.

```
    const [workoutSet, setWorkoutSet] = useState([
        { setNum: 1, reps: 10, weight: 0 },
        { setNum: 2, reps: 10, weight: 0 },
    ]);

    <SetList data={workoutSet} />
```

Within SetList I'm trying to render the data passed on to here.

```
export default function SetList(data) {
    return (
        <>
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={(item) => {
                    <Text style={styles.name}> {item} </Text>;
                }}
            />
            {console.log(data.data[0].reps)}
        </>
    );
}
```

`console.log(data.data[0].reps`) returns 10, as expected.

However, if I do a console.log inside renderItem, it doesn't print anything.  I'd like to access `setNum, reps and weight` inside `renderItem` so that I can display a list. What am I doing wrong? I've searched StackOverflow and couldn't find an answer to this. Thanks.

Comment: `data={data}` should be `data={data.data}`. Or alternatively you can destructure in the function parameter: `function SetList({ data })` (If you don't destructure, it's more conventional to call the argument `props`. Consistent naming is important to avoid confusion.)

Comment: make it like this and see what items is if you items is an object you will not see it on phone---like item.reps ---  renderItem={(item) => {console.log("item");return(
                    <Text style={styles.name}> {item} </Text>)
                }}

Comment: Ok i've changed data to props function SetList(props). Then I set data = {data.data}. But it's not returning anything. :(

Comment: <Text></Text> component  doesn't show objects

Comment: I can't even do a console.log(item) inside renderItem, which seems to be the issue here.

Comment: it should be `props.data` if you've changed the argument to `props`. Sorry if that wasn't clear (my fault for adding a separate afterthought to my main comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example
items in your render is an object thats why it is not showing
text component don't show object as text
i recommend reading about flatlist to understand more about it
-key extractors
-layouts

like best practices since it can be a problem for large lists (very slow performance for 100 rows)

working example
https://snack.expo.io/LpItecGOc